# How can I track which retargeting ad is clicked without using UTM parameters?

Tags: advertising, marketing, utm-parameters

I have this banner on my website that shows retargeting ads.I wonder if I can track which ad is getting how many clicks without adding UTM parameters.

[image]

Comment: You don't mention Google Analytics, but I assume that you are wanting to track it in GA because UTM parameters are for GA.  Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to capture something to identify the Ad with - you can record it as a custom event within Google Analytics.

Make sure the GA container has been created (pageview sent in your header) and then call this code:

ad_name is whatever variable you've captured to ID the ad (depends on provider)

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Ad Clicks', ad_name);
```

Comment: Clicks that leave the page often don't get tracked like that.  Event tracking is asynchronous and when the user clicks to leave the site the tracking often doesn't happen before the page is unloaded.   If the ad opens in a new window, then that is no problem.   It is possible to pass a callback function to the tracking that will set the `location.href` after the tracking has completed.   I usually use that for clicks that leave the page.